# Security constraint causes 404

Tags: jetty, resteasy, web.xml, keycloak

I'm  trying to secure part of my Resteasy rest services by adding Keycloak bearer-only token verification to my webapp.

In my web.xml I added:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>RestService</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>RestService</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.web.rest.ResteasyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm calling the url: `http://localhost:8090/rest/app`

This does work as far as authentication goes. Only requests with a valid token will get 'accepted' (others will result in a 401 error)

However, when I use this configuration, I always get a 404 error.

When I disable the security-constraint, the Resteasy controller hits the breakpoint and everything is fine. 
Do the mappings conflict with each other? How do I pass the request from the authentication phase to the Resteasy processing?

Comment: Can you please share your keycloak adapter configuration as well?

Comment: The 404 seems to be caused by the missing keycloak.json. I thought it was using an xml configuration alternative correctly, but it wasn't used, which is what caused keycloak to respond with 404

Answer (score 2):

In your `<login-config>` use `<auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>` instead of `BASIC`